# How to decode blob in Firebird

Tags: php, firebird, firebird2.5

I have an external application, which saves some data to a Firebird database. I need to read this data in my PHP application (but it can be Java or another language also).

Data is kept in table MY_TABLE with field MY_FIELD

Type of MY_FIELD is [BLOB SUB_TYPE 1]

I can export project from external application as file with SQL queries, for example:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_FIELD) VALUES ('20.00;0.28478;0.32461;0.38308;0.44478;0.51408;0.59144;0.66252;0.72157;0.78807;0.86791;0.96909;1.0557;1.1364;1.2523;1.3681;1.4814;1.6107;1.7551;1.8755;2.0008;2.1728;2.3557;2.5319;2.7193;2.9123;3.1122;3.3309;3.5565;3.8044;4.0627;4.3347;4.5754;4.8581;5.0925;5.3717;5.6047;5.835;6.0827;6.3306;6.5275;6.7589;6.9458;7.1962;7.3849;7.5213;7.6636;7.7756;7.8486;7.9299;7.9847;7.976;7.8689;7.8012;7.6962;7.611;7.5166;7.4203;7.3154;7.1768;7.0413;6.8516;6.6693;6.4958;6.2994;6.1245;5.9358;5.7431;5.5659;5.3819;5.1849;5.0036;4.821;4.639;4.4637;4.2965;4.1315;#...');
```

When I read record using PHP I can read:

0x000003cb00000082

Code below:

```
$query = 'SELECT MY_FIELD FROM MY_TABLE';
$result = ibase_query($firebirdConnection, $query);
$row = ibase_fetch_assoc ($result);
echo $row['MY_FIELD'];
```

I understand it's binary version of this text. I tried to decode it using php.

I used function ibase_blob_echo and I got mix of different characters:

x�%�Ǎ1��e������w?S%�h\E����,�6��\g��e�]�Y&��r8n5tW���_��3�¶�E'���k �lS�*>GS(�b�$�ť��]�3$1s�R�V�e���HRSn�z�����I6���Z3e��apj\־�v��-@w4�)����x���d�[�����/W�1�5O�+3��eT�fQM�i`����CC-���<9��%��Q�&�Q׈�g̯h��o��|'?�a�Y�����z�pI

Code below:

```
$result = ibase_query($firebirdConnection, $query);
$row = ibase_fetch_assoc ($result, IBASE_TEXT);
echo $row['MY_FIELD'];
```

Exacly the same effect I got when I add IBASE_TEXT flag to ibase_fetch_assoc:

```
$result = ibase_query($firebirdConnection, $query);
$row = ibase_fetch_assoc ($result, IBASE_TEXT);
echo $row['MY_FIELD'];
```

I use Firebird 2.5.

Is it possible to encode content of this database in external application?
Any idea?

Comment: `blob sub_type 1` (or `blob sub_type text`) is for **textual** data, not for binary data. For binary data, you need to use `blob sub_type binary` (or `blob sub_type 0`). However, as you seem to insert textual data, that shouldn't be a problem, however the value you decoded seems to be binary in nature. Without more details about what type of data it really is, it is not really possible to answer this.

Comment: "I understand it's binary version of this text" - no, it is a 'blob handle' value you have to use to fetch the blob data segments. If you can populate that BLOB by simple `insert` then the values there are supposedly short. You might try `select CAST(MY_FIELD AS VARCHAR(8190)) from MY_TABLE`

Comment: "when I add IBASE_TEXT flag" - your code above and below is identical, nothing removed or added

Comment: what `character set` do you specify in the connection of your application? What `character set` was specified for the blob field when it was created (it could implicitly inherit one from the then connection character set)? It seems your application can not guess the text encoding... You might try `ibase_blob_get` and see what is raw data there and then convert into the readable text. However because `but it can be Java or another language also` you better make sure to always specify connection character set.

Comment: In any case, in Java, using Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver), you can get the value with `getString` or `getCharacterStream` (if it is a string value), or `getBytes` or `getBinaryStream` (if it is a binary value), or - IMHO a more frustrating API - `getClob` / `getBlob`.